# The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

Tags: c#, rest, async-await

I am unclear as to why I am getting this message when the operation is actually marked as async.

Here is my test

```
public void TestMethod1()
   {

   SvcRestClient client =
            new SvcRestClient(new Uri("http://localhost:44395"),
                new AnonymousCredential());

   var tokenRequest = new TokenRequest
        {
            Username = "myusername",
            Password = "p@ssword1"
        };

   tokenRequest.Validate(); // passes

   var tokenResponse = await client.ApiRequestTokenPostWithHttpMessagesAsync(tokenRequest);  


    }
```

If I try to add the await I get a warning

[image]

Comment: It seems like we're missing some of your method. I don't see an await operator anywhere.

Comment: There maybe a couple of things going on here and there seems to be code missing, i don't see a `return` or an await in your second method, also you will probably want to let `async` and `awai`t propagate and return as an `async task `from your first method

Comment: oops, I updated to fix the paste error.

Comment: Click on the lightbulb, it's there for a reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your test method's signature to include `async` in order to await a task within the test.

```
public async Task TestMethod1() { // Codes to follow.
```

Comment: And then update the whole call chain... To anyone who uses this: don't use Wat or Result.